# CSS hover slide out flashes text too early

Tags: html, css

I have created a list of glyphicons, and when you hover over each glyphicon it displays expanding text.

The issue I am facing is that if the text is long it will flash over the glyphicon's container before the css transition has happened.

[Here is a fiddle example (notice the second box on hover).](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/xme7k0v1/8/)

I have tried playing around with the transitions and getting the text to display after the transition has finished.

My HTML:

```
<div class="myContainer">
  <div id="myNav">
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li class="listItem"><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="listItem"><a href="#">List Item 2 with long text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.subMenu .listItem {
  clear:both;
  list-style: none;
  height:15px;
  width: 15px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 10px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 12px 9px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}


.subMenu .listItem:hover {
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  cursor: auto;
  background: #fff
}


.subMenu .listItem a {
  color: transparent;
}

.subMenu .listItem:hover a{
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gjbm3v6z/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put `overflow:hidden;` in `.listItem` and force the line not break using `white-space:nowrap;` on the link.

[new code fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xme7k0v1/9/)

final code:

```
#myNav {
  width: 50%;
}

.subMenu .listItem {
  clear:both;
  list-style: none;
  height:15px;
  width: 15px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 10px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 12px 9px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.subMenu .listItem:hover {
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  cursor: auto;
  background: #fff
}


.subMenu .listItem a {
  color: transparent;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.subMenu .listItem:hover a{
  color: #000;
}
```

hope this helps. =D